# getting hibernate exception when i upload image

Tags: java, hibernate

my controller class is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profilePictureUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("fileExtension") String fileExtension, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,HttpServletRequest request) {

     logger.info("In add profile Picture Upload");  
     String mediaResponse=null;;
     try {
         String token = request.getHeader("authToken");
         System.out.println("+++++++++++++++token+++++++++++++++++++"+token );
            User user = userDao.findUserByAuthToken(token);
            System.out.println("+++++++++++++++USER+++++++++++++++++++"+user );
            System.out.println("+++++++++++++++file.getBytes()+++++++++++++++++++"+file.getBytes() );
            if (user != null) {

                  Physician physicain=physicainDao.findPhysicianById(user.getPhysicianId().getPhysicianId());
                  String fileStoragPath=userOriginalServerPath+"/"+physicain.getPhysicianId();
                  File file1=new File(fileStoragPath);
                  file1.mkdirs();
                  String filePath=fileStoragPath+"/"+physicain.getPhysicianId()+System.currentTimeMillis()+fileExtension;
                  FileOutputStream fileOuputStream =new FileOutputStream(filePath); 
                  fileOuputStream.write(file.getBytes());
                  fileOuputStream.close();  
                  /**
                   * Creating thumbnail for media upload
                   */
                  File thumbnailPath=new File(userThumbnailFilePath+physicain.getPhysicianId());
                  thumbnailPath.mkdirs();
                  String thumbnail_path=physicain.getPhysicianId()+"/"+physicain.getPhysicianId()+System.currentTimeMillis()+fileExtension;

                  Thumbnails.of(new File(filePath)).size(75, 75).toFile(new File(userThumbnailFilePath+thumbnail_path));
                  physicain.setProfileImage("MedikmUserPicture/thumbnail/"+thumbnail_path);
                  physicainDao.update(physicain);   
                  mediaResponse="MedikmUserPicture/thumbnail/"+thumbnail_path;

             }else{
                  mediaResponse=MedikmConstants.USER_INVALID_AUTHENTICATION__MESSAGE;

             } 
            System.out.println("================mediaResponse============"+mediaResponse);
            return mediaResponse;

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Error in media tag Method :"+ex);
            return mediaResponse=MedikmConstants.USER_INVALID_AUTHENTICATION__MESSAGE;
        }

 }
```

and by uploading image  getting hibernate exception like

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102)
```

image is getting upload successfully but don't know why i am getting this exception field name of physician class is i mapped

```
 @Column(name = "Profile_Image")
private String profileImage;
```

please help me to get me out from this exception.

Comment: Are you trying to upload the image as String? That is wrong. Save it as byte-array. Multipart file has getBytes method, use it. Secondly, you must disable Batch update to see the actual error and post more error information. Lastly, too much logic you have in your controller method, move it to service layer.

Comment: thakn you for reply exception is Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Profile_Image' at
2015-09-16 17:02:09,598 ERROR [org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener] (http-apr-8080-exec-4) - Could not synchronize database state with sessio
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)'

Comment: Like I said, disable your batch updates in your config, so you will have errors properly. Also, don't post errors in comment, edit your main post and put them there.

Comment: i'm not  saving the image in String

Comment: Last time, post error log with batch in main post, clean up your code.

Comment: @Sumit what is the type of column Profile_Image in your database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Profile_Image** sholud be either **TINYBLOB**,**BLOB**,**MEDIUMBLOB**,**LONGBLOB**

Depending on your needs, as:

- TINYBLOB: maximum length of 255 bytes
- BLOB: maximum length of 65,535 bytes
- MEDIUMBLOB: maximum length of 16,777,215 bytes
- LONGBLOB: maximum length of 4,294,967,295 bytes

So you have to update your **Profile_Image** column

example: if you set your column MEDIUMBLOB it's mapping should be :-

```
@Lob
@Column(name="Profile_Image",columnDefinition="mediumblob")
private byte[] profileImage;
```

**Note :** i got this error while saving a very big image and my data type was **Blob** and i was using **mysql** `Packet for query is too large . You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet variable.`

after some searching i found that

> You must increase this value if you are using large BLOB columns or
>   long strings. It should be as big as the largest BLOB you want to use.
>   The protocol limit for max_allowed_packet is 1GB. The value should be
>   a multiple of 1024; nonmultiples are rounded down to the nearest
>   multiple.

so i found `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024*1024*number of MB`

i.e.

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024*1024*14
```

this will set the max size of allowed packet 14 GB,make sure you restart MySQL for change to take effect

See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-image-into-database/) and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-load-or-save-image-using) full examples to save image in hibernate